# Change the value of scope variable AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**tl;dr**: change the value of scope variable and based on this rerender a directive. If I use `isAccepted: '=?'` `I receive Expression used with directive '' is non-assignable!`if I use `isAccepted: '@'` it doesn't work (isAccepted value changes, but the view doesn't reren.

Here's a scope of my playerView:

```
scope: {
      isAccepted: '=?',
      player: '='
    },
```

If `isAccepted=true` I wanna show a div with a green icon (otherwise I show a div with a gray icon) to show the player's view:

```
<div class="player-green-container" ng-if="::ctrl.isAccepted">
<div class="player-gray-container" ng-if="::!ctrl.isAccepted">
```

The problem is that if a user presses on a icon I want it to display the other div (gray -> green, green -> gray), so if a user presses gray icon we should change the value of `this.isAccepted` (I did it already) and (the most important part) I didn't manage to work: to rerender `.html` directive.

**UPD**: some code from directive:

```
<div class="player-list">
  <comment-view class="player-list-item"
                player="p"
                is-accepted="ctrl.playerIds.indexOf(p.id) > -1"></comment-view>
</div>
```

In my controller I've got the following:

```
@export {boolean}
this.isAccepted;
```

Here's my directive:

When I replace `@ with =` `console.log(this.isAccepted)` outputs either true, false, but if I replace `= with @` console.log outputs outputs string value: `"ctrl.playerIds.indexOf(p.id) > -1"`

Is there any way I can force it to evaluate to true/false (still using '@') (I tried `eval()` and it doesn't work - I still get a string)?

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include more of your code?   Specifically the html code you're using include your directive.

Comment: @MichaelLynch updated a question: so I figure out a way to pass boolean it'll work I believe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use `@` as your binding method, In your html change the `is-accepted` to:

```
<div class="player-list">
    <comment-view class="player-list-item"
                  player="p"
                  is-accepted="{{ctrl.playerIds.indexOf(p.id) > -1}}">
    </comment-view>
</div>
```

Placing your code in `{{brackets}}` will evaluate it.  If you then want to get  notify your parent that a change was made, create a callback method such as `acceptedChanged='&'`.

The reason you were getting "is not assignable" error when using `=` is because `ctrl.playerIds.indexOf(p.id) > -1` is not a variable that you can assign to.  (Imagine `ctrl.playerIds.indexOf(p.id) > -1 = (something)`, thats not valid syntax)

Comment: Thanks, actually I managed to get it by myself randomly! The only problem that's left is that with this directive the actual values of `isAccepted` is OK (true or false, I printed them out in a onInit()), but still all <divs> are greens (like if ng-if doesn't work).

Comment: is there any way to force evaluate it to boolean?
ng-if="ctrl.isAccepted"

I believe it thinks that "false" is kinda a string.

Comment: The problem is that actual values of isAccepted are right, but for some strange reason ctrl.isAccepted evaluates as true for every player.

Comment: I was just writing that its getting passed as a string.  You can change the `@` to `<` to use one way binding instead (with this i believe you should remove the `{{}}` in your html)

Comment: well, I can probably use ng-if="ctrl.isAccepted== 'false'" then

Comment: Do you mean like this: `isAccepted: '<?'`?

Comment: give me 1 minute, i'll write it up in a plunkr.

Comment: Well, '<' seems to work in terms of printing out true/false, but it doesn't solve the main problem: when I manually update isAccepted=false the directive doesn't get updated (e.g., if it was green and isAccepted=true, when I manually set isAccepted=false the component is still green) :(

Comment: Okay so here is the plunkr I made around this.   https://plnkr.co/edit/VHgXGIiuhUt3TakoRBP6

Are you wanting the isAccepted to be updated in the parent?

Comment: Cool, thanks. I wanna to be able to update from player-view-controller, so I'd say initially the value gets from scope from parent but then I'd like to manually change accepted -> notAccepted and want view to react to these changes.

Comment: Where should I press to change isAccepted for a player in your example?

Comment: Well, I use '@' locally but the reloading stopped working. So true/false is OK, but when I change a boolean variable isAccepted view doesn't reload.

Comment: Okay so if you want to update the parent, you'll either need to make a function call or pass something that is editable.   Checkout: https://plnkr.co/edit/VHgXGIiuhUt3TakoRBP6?p=preview

Comment: Looks exactly what I need! Thanks! How can I pass sth that editable though?

Comment: You could have a `isAccepted` field on your player object.  Then if passed your player via two way binding (`=`), if you changed `player.isAccepted = true` it would update it in your parent controller.   You could also do this with one way binding and a function call `playerChanged` passing the new player.

Comment: Got the 1st one entirely. Is the latter is the one use you use on plunker? Thank you so much!